# How to Tag Friends in Facebook Video using Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to tag friends in facebook video, using Facebook API,
I am coding in PHP.

In **[Permission Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)**,

There are permissions

```
user_photo_video_tags   
friends_photo_video_tags
```

But I don't see anything mentioned in **[Facebook API reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/)**

Comment: It does work now. See my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461678/is-it-possible-to-tag-friends-in-video-with-graph-api/22335788#22335788

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's on this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/#tags

---

oops, my bad. video tagging is not supported. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/, at least not by the Graph API.

Comment: This link is for tagging photo, I want to tag video.

Comment: Thanks for information, I hope they release it soon. It saved lot of my time searching for one.

Comment: Are there any API's yet which we can use to tag videos? Or is there any other option available yet?