# Is it possible to tag friends in video with graph api?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I haven't find anything related. Might be i would have searched wrongly.
I want to tag friends in video.

How do i do that using graph api in facebook?

Comment: Have you Googled `tag friends in video with graph api`? I see some promising results, check them out

Comment: ok. it seems we cant tag friends in video with graph api. Thanks for the keywords.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to tag friends in a video, but it's just not in the documentation. I've searched quite some time myself to no avail, but then tried a couple of things and got it working.

The two permissions you need are publish_actions and user_videos.

It works quite similar to tagging photos, which is done with the `/{photo_id}/tags` endpoint. Although the video equivalent `/{video_id}/tags` is nowhere to be found in the documenation, it apparently does exist.
With photos you can supply the parameter `tags` as an array. Video tagging only supports one tag at a time with the `tag_uid` parameter. So if you want to tag multiple people, you'll have to do multiple posts.

This is the final working solution with the PHP SDK:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array('[YOUR_APP_ID]', '[YOUR_APP_SECRET]'));

$response = $facebook->api('/me/videos', 'POST', array(
    'access_token' => $facebook->getAccessToken(),
    'title'        => '[YOUR_TITLE]',
    'description'  => '[YOUR_DESCRIPTION]',
    'source'       => '@' . realpath('[PATH_TO_YOUR_VIDEO')
));

$facebook->api('/' . $response['id'] . '/tags', 'POST', array(
    'access_token' => $facebook->getAccessToken(),
    'tag_uid'      => '[FRIENDS_FACEBOOK_ID]'
));
```

Comment: Note that this worked for V1.0 of the Facebook API. This probably has changed (at least the syntax) as of V2.0 (and up). Not to mention the app review you need to pass to use these extended permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Read this
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

The post supports adding message tags.

Under the `message_tags column`

> object containing fields whose names are the indexes to where objects are mentioned in the message field; each field in turn is an array containing an object with id, name, offset, and length fields, where length is the length, within the message field, of the object mentioned